# Dual Boot cause Ubuntu and Windows to crash

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, recovery-mode

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer, dual booting with Windows 8.1. Now, I am unable to use either system. When it boots and I select Ubuntu, the login in page flashed and then turns to black with the error 4.08533 APCI PCC. When I try to login to windows (including recovery mode) it appears saying "The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors."

Answer (score 1):

Just try to use Boot Repair Disk that is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues.

1-You need to download it from here.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

2- Install ISO file to live USB by using UnetBootin or liliUSB or Universal USB Installer.

Note: Live USB is recomended. Don't use live CD please.

3-When you boot your machine with your live USB; a new window will open.

[image]

4- Recommended repair, solve more common issues. If you have no idea what to do, do not use Advanced options.

Note: In Boot-Repair-Disk system tools, there is also a OS-Uninstaller. After Uninstaller one of your OS you may need to use Boot repair again.

[For more information, visit this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks to warning. I have limited time, as soon as possible I will change it.

Comment: Why _Live USB_ and not _Live CD_ ?

Comment: Remark : it is recommended to install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer). Do not burn it on a DVD if your computer has Windows8 pre-installed, or if your boot is in EFI mode. (From Ubuntu wiki)